# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 from fstream cpp

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, app-bundle

I wrote a cross platform cpp application and wish to create a *.app bundle for osx. Compiling and running as unix-executable works just fine. Using

```
SET(MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME ${appName})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${appName} PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE)
```

in my CMakeLists.txt I get an app bundle, but the program crashes when trying to read resources using ifstream I located inside the bundle, paths are correct. Tried chmod +x and google but to no success.

Comment: Could you add a bit more to your question — specifically focus on what you did on the macOS side (keeping any other OS config aside).